# Latest security update breaks encryptfs authentication screen

Tags: full-disk-encryption

I applied the most recent security update to elementaryOS and I no long get an authentication screen when booting - the screen is blank.

By chance, I typed in the correct decrypt password and was able to login as normal.  This is a big miss on details.

I'm running Elementary OS on VMWare on a Mac running MacOS 10.13.6.